# load a file (taglib.tag) in a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsp, load, taglib

here is my problem :
I want to load a file (test.tag) in a div with jquery on a button click.

Here is the code :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="test" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/test"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="views" tagdir="/WEB-INF/views/desktop/test"%>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changePage(page) {

        if(page!=null) {    
        $("#newPage") = $("#newPage").replaceWith('<div id="newPage" class="tab_content"></div>'); // to delete the previous content
        $("#newPage").load("test:"+page+".tag");
        $("#newPage").fadeIn();
    }
    return false;
}
</script>

<button onclick="changePage('test')">test</button>

<div id="newPage" class="tab_content"></div>
```

i already tried to input some html :

```
$("#newPage").html("<test:"+page+"></test:"+page+">");
```

but didn't work either.

Can you help me? ^^

Comment: So you're trying to load the html generated from a jsp custom tag into your page using javascript?

Comment: exactly ^^
In fact I can already display differents pages with jQuery but there are as much div as page I want to display. The problem is, if I want to be able to display 40 differents pages, I need 40 divs (and 40 pages will be loaded :/). That's why I wanna try to make a dynamic load ^^

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing client versus server evaluation of your custom tag.  You can definitely use javascript to put

```
<mytaglib:tagname></mytaglib:tagname>
```

into your DOM on the client side, but it will become the literal content of #newPage.  Custom tags are evaluated on the server side.  By the time the javascript executes on the client side, you're no longer in jsp territory, you're in html.

**jsp1.jsp**:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="test" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/test"%>
<test:page1></test:page1>
```

You can load it like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "/jsp1.jsp", 
    dataType:"html",
    success: function(markup) {
        $("#newPage").html(markup);
    }
})
```

If you need to pass parameters, make them attributes of the custom tag, and send the values as request parameters in your ajax request.  For example:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="test" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/test"%>
<test:mytag pageId=${param.id}></test:mytag>
```

Comment: You can use ajax to load the output of a jsp that contains the custom tag code.  Create a separate jsp for each unique use of the custom tag (different content or attributes), and then use the url of the proper jsp as the ajax url.  You'll get back the html generated by your custom tag, which you put into your page using jquery.  The jsps can be very short - just the taglib declaration and the tag itself.

Comment: here is the code I try to use now :

$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "#",
    context:$("#newPage"),
    dataType:"html",
    data:"<%@ taglib prefix='comp' tagdir='/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/test'%><test:test></test:test>",
    processData:false
   });

and the error is "no tag in the tag library with the prefix test" :/